# What is the correct way of using a config file?

Tags: java, xml, properties, config

I would like to use an XML config file for my application, something like this:

```
<defaults>
 <timeout>3000</timeout>
 <delay>200</delay>
..... etc
```

I would like to use these properties in multiple classes. The way I am doing it at the moment is reading the xml file in a static class and store them in static final properties like:

```
public static final int TIMEOUT;
```

and then in another class I read it like:

```
int timeout = Properties.TIMEOUT;
```

where Properties is the class where I store those static variables.
Having never worked with config files before, I do realize this is not the correct way to handle them. So my question is, what is the good way using a XML config file throughout a java application, and/or is there a design pattern for this to be used?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: You might find this useful as a reference, or just include it in your project.  http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/

Comment: Are you interested in a single threaded environment or are we talking about a server?

Comment: No, no server, just a single threaded.

Comment: Why do you think your approach is wrong? I don't see any issue by reading the config file when the application starts and share the Properties among classes and threads. The data are immutable anyway.

Comment: I would prefer not having to use external libraries as it may be problem in our company, even if it's opensource. I am more interested in the way of reading the config file once and then used these properties in different classes. Or is it more common reading the properties from different classes as you need them?

Answer (score 0):

Like you wrote, usually a [properties-file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) is used for config. It comes in the format of:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
...
```

It's really not complicated to use - you can practically pick it up in less than 5 mins. Here's a nice [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) for using a properties-file.

**UPDATE**

In case you have to use an XML file - I would use any XML parser (JAXB/XStream...) and create a hashMap that'll hold the pairs of key/value - same like it's done with properties-file.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into the Property file before, but we do need tp use a xml file. As I said above, I am more interested in the way of reading the config file once and then used these properties in different classes.

Comment: @Dave see **UPDATE** section

Comment: @Dave - java.util.Properties also has a `loadFromXML(InputStream)` method. See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML(java.io.InputStream))